# passing an id in django homepage url

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to create a blog using django.

I have truncated the post such that you have to click on the post to read the entire post.essentially, you should be redirected to article.html where you get to read the entire blog post. If I try to go to my `article.html/1`, I can read the post, but if I try to do the sane using `blog.id` in my homepage, I  get an error.

This is my `welcome.html` code:

```
<a href="{%url 'article' blog.id %}"><p>{pic.post | truncatewords:10 }}</p></button></a>
```

My urls are as follows:

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.welcome,name = 'welcome'),
    url(r'^post/', views.post, name='post'),
    url(r'^article/(\d+)', views.article, name='article'),
    url(r'^search/', views.search_results, name='search_results'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my views

```
def welcome(request):
    pics=Blog.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'welcome.html', {"pics":pics})

def post(request):
    form= PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.save()
        return redirect('welcome')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'post.html', {"form":form})

def search_results(request):
    if 'article' in request.GET and request.GET["article"]:
        search_term = request.GET.get("article")
        print(search_term)

        blogs = Blog.search_results(search_term)
        message = f"{search_term}"

        return render(request  'search.html'{"message":message,"blogs": blogs})
    else:
        message = "You haven't searched for any term"
        return render(request, 'search.html',{"message":message})

def article(request, blog_id):
     pics =Blog.objects.filter(id = blog_id)
     return render(request, 'article.html', {"pics":pics, id:blog_id})
```

However, ever time I try to click on the post so that I can be redirected to the `article.html` (so that I can read the entire post) I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'article' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['article/(\\d+)']
```

Where I'm I going wrong?

Comment: You haven't got anything called `blog` in your home page. What is that `blog.id` supposed to refer to? You probably need to show more of that welcome.html template.

Answer (score 4):

In your welcome view, you are passing the **blog queryset** as **pics** to context.

And in your template you are using `pic.post` to access the post content. So I would assume you loop through the posts like this `{% for pic in pics %}`

If so you could try to access the id using `pic.id` so your url would be:

`{% url 'article' pic.id %}`.

Comment: thank you, i've used pic.id as you've suggested and it now works fine.